# Grunt + Express + LiveReload keeps restarting server on default port 3000

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, livereload

I've got a Handlebars-driven template app that is generated via a simple Express-based Node.js server. I've been working to set it up to live reload using Grunt for ease of development.

I've read a myriad of blogs and GitHub readmes about setting up live reloading; this proved to be a very cyclical chore (one page links to another which leads to another, and another, and so on). Nothing I read was consistent, and *everything* seems to support live reloading without actually explaining how to do it -- it was quite a struggle to find a definitive approach to doing this!

However, I've got a working, self-reloading, Express-driven project, via the following:

**Gruntfile.js**

```
var files = [
    'markup/*',
    'examples/*'
]

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt)
    grunt.initConfig({
        express: {
            options: {
                port: 8080
            },
            dev: {
                options: {
                    port: 8080,
                    script: 'server.js',
                    background: true
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            options: {
                livereload: true
            },
            express: {
                files: files,
                tasks: ['express:dev'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
        },
    })
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['express:dev', 'watch'])
}
```

**Package.json**

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    "connect-livereload": "^0.5.4",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-express-server": "^0.5.3",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.5.0"
}
...
```

**In my Express app, server.js:**

```
// Live reload
app.use(require('connect-livereload')({
    port: 35729
}))

// Server
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function() {
    console.log("Express app started on port " + server.address().port)
})
```

**And in my Handlebars-driven index.html template:**

```
<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

Everything is now actually working -- I simply run `$ grunt` from the project directory, and the page loads; it then reloads as expected when I change a file on the back end.

---

**The problem:**

When I fire up the project with grunt, the following happens:

```
> $ grunt
Running "express:dev" (express) task
Starting background Express server
Express app started on port 8080

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "components/el.html" changed.

Running "express:web" (express) task
Stopping Express server
Starting background Express server
>> File "components/el.html" changed.

Running "express:dev" (express) task
Stopping Express server
Starting background Express server
Express app started on port 3000

Running "watch:web" (watch) task
Completed in 0.491s at Thu May 19 2016 12:37:33 GMT-0700 (PDT) - Waiting...
Express app started on port 8080

Running "watch" task
Completed in 0.484s at Thu May 19 2016 12:37:33 GMT-0700 (PDT) - Waiting...
```

Notice how the Express app is now listening on *both* `:3000` and `:8080`? What's going on? I'm assuming it's something in my gruntfile that isn't set up right?